# copy and replace file in tcl

Tags: linux, tcl, file-handling

I am using the following tcl command:

```
file copy ?-force? file1 file2
```

here 'file1' and 'file2' are text files having same names, I want to copy file1 from the location by moving up the parent directory and replace the file2 located in the current directory. So I want to perform something like this:

- step1: cd ../../
- step2: copy 'file1.txt' from the step1 location
- step3: now move to the current directory
- step4: replace 'file2.txt' with 'file1.txt'

I don't know how to mention the path in the 'file copy' command ?  It would be also better if you mention the shortcut to navigate like in step1 but for a longer path. So I can skip writing manually a longer path. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
file copy -force ../../file1.txt file2.txt
```

You can't copy a file like you do in a GUI. The `file copy` command immediately creates a copy of the source file in the target location. Both the source and target arguments are file names (or possibly a directory name for the target) including full paths, so you simply join up the path with the base file name.

I'm not sure what you mean by "shortcut to navigate". The command for changing the current directory is `cd`, with the path to a directory as argument. But, again, you don't need to change directory to copy a file.

Documentation: [cd](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/cd.htm), [file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm)